# How to identify type of an javascript object field which is a Array<{}>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have JavaScript object which comes from a request which may include nested fields, I need to identify field which is a type of Array<{}> and i need to iterate that field alone, but in javascript i could not able to achieve that. anyone please suggest me a solution to find the field based on field type.

sample object

```
const obj = {
name:'jane', 
age: 22,
interested_books:[{book_name:'xxx', author_name:'yyy'}, {book_name:'aaa', author_name:'zzz'}],
hobbies:['reading', 'football'],
address:{street_name:'dace street', door_no:12}
}
```

Among these fields, I need to iterate the field which is an Array<{}>(i.e interested_books)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have types like `Array<{}>`. Are you talking about TypeScript?

Comment: yes, its an typescript @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `Object.entires()` and `isArray` to check if it's an array

```js
obj = {
  name: "jane",
  age: 22,
  interested_books: [
    { book_name: "xxx", author_name: "yyy" },
    { book_name: "aaa", author_name: "zzz" },
  ],
  hobbies: ["reading", "football"],
  address: { street_name: "dace street", door_no: 12 },
};
function getArrWithOb(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
Object.entries(obj).filter((o) => {
  if (Array.isArray(o[1])) {
    if (o[1].every((ob) => typeof ob == "object")) {
      return o;
    }
  }
})
  );
}
console.log(getArrWithOb(obj));
```

From the comments it looks like what you want to be returned is the name of the property
You could use `reduce`

```js
obj = { name: "jane", age: 22, interested_books: [ { book_name: "xxx", author_name: "yyy" }, { book_name: "aaa", author_name: "zzz" }, ], hobbies: ["reading", "football"], address: { street_name: "dace street", door_no: 12 }, };
function getArrWithOb(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, o) => {
    if (Array.isArray(o[1])) {
      if (o[1].every((ob) => typeof ob == "object")) {
        r.push(o[0]);
      }
    }
    return r;
  }, []);
}
console.log(getArrWithOb(obj));
```

Comment: this is iterating array type as well, i need to iterate field which is array<{}>, maybe getting a field as an output also fine(i.e `interested_books`)

Comment: I have updated my answer check it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: is it possible to get the key name as a output aswell?

Comment: I have updated my answer let me know if it works for you

Comment: Nope, i just need `interested_books` as an output, function should return instead of console.log()

Comment: console.log() it's just to log the results do you mean you want to wrap the code in a function ?

Comment: I wrapped the code in a function the console.log part at the end is just to show the result

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to get field name as an o/p(i.e `interested_books`)

Comment: do you mean you want only the field name as an output ?? can you show me an example of your expected output ?

Comment: expected o/p `'interested_books'` I

Comment: I have added another example that returns `'interested_books'`

Answer (score 2):

Use [isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if value is an array

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'jane',
  age: 22,
  interested_books: [{
    book_name: 'xxx',
    author_name: 'yyy'
  }, {
    book_name: 'aaa',
    author_name: 'zzz'
  }],
  hobbies: ['reading', 'football'],
  address: {
    street_name: 'dace street',
    door_no: 12
  }
}

for (let keys in obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[keys])) {
    obj[keys].forEach(item => console.log(item))
  }
}
```

Comment: this is iterating array type as well, i need to iterate field which is array<{}>, maybe getting a field as an output also fine(i.e `interested_books`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `instanceof`

```js
const obj = {
name:'jane', 
age: 22,
interested_books:[{book_name:'xxx', author_name:'yyy'}, {book_name:'aaa', author_name:'zzz'}],
hobbies:['reading', 'football'],
address:{street_name:'dace street', door_no:12}
}

for (const v in obj) obj[v] instanceof Array && console.log(obj[v]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'jane',
  age: 22,
  interested_books: [{
    book_name: 'xxx',
    author_name: 'yyy'
  }, {
    book_name: 'aaa',
    author_name: 'zzz'
  }],
  hobbies: ['reading', 'football'],
  address: {
    street_name: 'dace street',
    door_no: 12
  }
}

for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
    console.log('I am array', key);
    const isArrayOfObject = obj[key].every(item => typeof item === "object");
    if (isArrayOfObject) {
      // your_logic_here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below. This is to get the items in the object that are arrays.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'jane',
  age: 22,
  interested_books: [{ book_name: 'xxx', author_name: 'yyy' }, { book_name: 'aaa', author_name: 'zzz' }],
  hobbies: ['reading', 'football'],
  address: { street_name: 'dace street', door_no: 12 }
};

const getArraysFromObject = obj => {
  const results = {};
  Object.keys(obj).map(field => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[field])) {
      results[field] = obj[field];
    }
  });
  return results;
};

console.log(results); 
// {
//   "interested_books": [
//     { "book_name": "xxx", "author_name": "yyy" },
//     { "book_name": "aaa", "author_name": "zzz" }
//   ],
//   "hobbies": ["reading", "football"]
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **typeof** to check if value is an array

```js
const obj = {
name:'jane', 
age: 22,
interested_books:[{book_name:'xxx', author_name:'yyy'}, {book_name:'aaa', author_name:'zzz'}],
hobbies:['reading', 'football'],
address:{street_name:'dace street', door_no:12}
}

for (x in obj) {
  txt = obj[x];
  if(typeof(txt) == "object")
  {
    for(oj in txt)
    {
      ojval = txt[oj];
      console.log(ojval);
    }
  }
}
```